# React app showing blank page after deploying on firebase

Tags: reactjs, firebase, deployment, firebase-hosting

My react app is working perfectly fine on localhost but when i deployed it on firebase hosting, it is showing blank page. It is showing this :
[image]

I looked up on internet and stack overflow, there are alot of similar solutions, I tried them all but nothing works for me, that is why i am asking again. My firebase.json file looks like this

```
    {
  "hosting": {
    "public": "build",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

My package.json file looks like this

```
{
  "name": "my-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.11.0",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^4.9.1",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.3.2",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.1.2",
    "firebase": "^7.23.0",
    "firebase-admin": "^9.2.0",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-currency-format": "^1.0.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "3.4.3"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

What should I need to do to work it perfectly on firebase hosting ? Any help is appreciated ?

Comment: Any console errors? If so, add them to the question. There's been a bunch of Stack Overflow posts on this exact issue already, did you read them and try things from those? At a glance could be cos you have `"public": "build"`, but in production things are put in a `dist` folder, not a `build` one

Comment: @Jayce444 There is no console errors as far as i know. It is working  perfectly on `npm start` on localhost:3000. Also `npm run build` done with no errors, `firebase deploy` done perfectly. Yes I have read and tried all the currently available solutions but nothing works.  On doing `"public":dist` firebase deploy gives error that there is no such directory. Also I found that build works good when hosting react app on firebase, so i think that is not a problem... there must be something else i am missing..